# How to implement the execution of a language that I am writing?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, delegates, stack-overflow

I am writing my own programming language using C# just for fun. It's called SPL. It has only 12 keywords/commands/instructions and nothing more. I know exactly what each command is going to do. This is the class diagram:

[image]

This is not finished of course. But the idea is, we have a runtime `ISplRuntime`. All the things that the commands do, is done on the runtime. For example, the `OutputCommand` outputs the stuff in `ISplRuntime.Current` (This is just an `object`) to `ISplRuntime.Output` (This is a `TextWriter`).

So far so good. But then I need to implement the `IGotoCommand` which is just like the `goto` keyword in C#. I am going to make three kinds of gotos. But I cannot figure out how to change the flow of the program.

Here's the ideas I tried:

Add a method called `RunNextCommand()` in `ISplRuntime`. And in the end of every command's `Execute()` method, call `RunNextCommand`. However, if the user writes a lot of SPL code, the stack trace will get larger and larger and result in a Stack Overflow.

Add a delegate to `ISplRuntime`. Each time a command has finished executing, `Invoke()` the delegate. The delegate will look for the next command to execute and call `Execute()` on that `ICommand`. But I am not sure if this will also result in a stack overflow. **Will it result in a stack overflow?**

I am still not very sure if this is the right way to do it. I just want an general answer about how to do this kind of thing as this is the first time for me to write a language. Also please tell me whether using delegates will cause a stack overflow.

Comment: Why not insert the goto operation into IL?

Comment: Your program is a list of instructions.  When you execute you are going to increment the index to the list of instruction as you execute each instruction.  A goto will cause the index to jump instead of just increment by one.

Comment: I would encourage anyone writing a programming language to read "The Dragon Book" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools). Even if you're not writing a full-blown compiler, and even though the book is targeted at the C programmer, there is a great deal you will learn by reading it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, you would just do a loop; within the loop, execute the command at the current line, then for all non-flow-control commands increment the current line. For goto, just set the current line to the parameter. There are no stack issues because the flow is not recursive - everything gets launched from the instruction loop (which would belong to the runtime, given your class diagram).

Comment: Let me paraphrase what you mean because I am not sure if I fully understood. You want me just to leave the Execute method of the goto command blank. And when client code implements ISplRuntime, it needs to write a loop to execute the commands. In the loop, it needs to check whether the current command is a goto. If it is, then change the loop index. Am I interpreting you correctly?

Comment: Not quite. Let's try this: each command has `NextCommand` method. Commands are divided into `FlowControlCommand` and `SimpleCommand`. `SimpleCommand`'s `NextCommand` will return current line + 1. goto's `NextCommand` will return the line specified by the goto. Your runtime has a while loop that does `currentCommand.Execute`, then `currentLine = currentCommand.NextCommand(currentLine)`. I may have misunderstood the purpose of your `ISplRuntime` - basically, there's probably a place where the client says `myIsplProgram.Run()` - that is where you have a loop.

Comment: Ok I understand it now! Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

> I am writing my own programming language using C# just for fun.

Awesome!

> Add a method called RunNextCommand() in ISplRuntime. And in the end of every command's Execute() method, call RunNextCommand.

Even before you realize that its a stack overflow to do so, you should realize that your description of `RunNextCommand` does not do what it says on the tin. What you are describing is called `RunRemainderOfProgram`. That's a sign that something is messed up in this design.

> Add a delegate to ISplRuntime. Each time a command has finished executing, Invoke() the delegate. The delegate will look for the next command to execute and call Execute() on that ICommand. But I am not sure if this will also result in a stack overflow. Will it result in a stack overflow?

I don't see why it would. So the idea here is that `RunNextCommand` as its last action sets a delegate which, when invoked, does the next command?

What you have invented here is called a *continuation*. The continuation of an instruction is the "what happens next?" of the current point of execution.

> I am still not very sure if this is the right way to do it. I just want an general answer about how to do this kind of thing as this is the first time for me to write a language.

There are many ways to build an interpreter, which is basically what you're doing here. I would continue to experiment and see what works and what doesn't.

It might help to study how this problem is solved in virtual and actual machines. In those machines every instruction has a unique number associated with it; a "goto" contains the number of the next instruction to run. There is a special variable called the "instruction pointer" which has the number of the currently-running instruction. If the current instruction is a goto, then the IP is set to the value indicated by the goto; if not, the IP is incremented to the next instruction, and so on. The main loop is then "look up the instruction at the current IP, execute it, set the new IP, repeat".

> Also please tell me whether using delegates will cause a stack overflow.

It's hard to predict the behaviour of a program we can't see and you haven't written. Try it and you will very quickly find out if you've written an unbounded recursion.

Good luck!